# pocketsphinx can't efficiently recognize words (commands) recorded via mic

Tags: c, linux, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx

I compiled this example C code of speech recognition librry pocketsphinx on my debian 9 system.

I recorded a sample audio in a file called goforward.raw which has the command: "go forward" in it.

Neither the pockesphinx_continuous programs efficiently recognizes words recorded via headphones using the arecord tool on linux, nor does the example code given does it. Just partial recognition i.e it recognizes the "go forward" command as "move forward" and that's ok but other commands are very badly recognized. If you say hello, it turns it to who are you.?

The interesting thing is that audio files created using Text to Speech tool pico2wave are recognized very efficiently like 80% accuracy when it comes to extracting words from a wav file created via pico2wave tool.

```
Here is the example pockesphinx code:

#include <pocketsphinx.h>


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ps_decoder_t *ps;
    cmd_ln_t *config;
    FILE *fh;
    char const *hyp, *uttid;
    int16 buf[512];
    int rv;
    int32 score;

    config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
                 "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
                 "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
                 "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
                 NULL);
    if (config == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create config object, see log for details\n");
    return -1;
    }

    ps = ps_init(config);
    if (ps == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create recognizer, see log for details\n");
    return -1;
    }

    fh = fopen("goforward.raw", "rb");
    if (fh == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file goforward.raw\n");
    return -1;
    }

    rv = ps_start_utt(ps);

    while (!feof(fh)) {
    size_t nsamp;
    nsamp = fread(buf, 2, 512, fh);
    rv = ps_process_raw(ps, buf, nsamp, FALSE, FALSE);
    }

    rv = ps_end_utt(ps);
    hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, &score);
    printf("Recognized: %s\n", hyp);

    fclose(fh);
    ps_free(ps);
    cmd_ln_free_r(config);

    return 0;
}
```

> and here is the pocketsphinx_continuous tool code provided by the official package from pocketsphinx:

```
/* -*- c-basic-offset: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil -*- */
/* ====================================================================
 * Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Carnegie Mellon University.  All rights
 * reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. 
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 *    distribution.
 *
 * This work was supported in part by funding from the Defense Advanced 
 * Research Projects Agency and the National Science Foundation of the 
 * United States of America, and the CMU Sphinx Speech Consortium.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY CARNEGIE MELLON UNIVERSITY ``AS IS'' AND 
 * ANY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, 
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL CARNEGIE MELLON UNIVERSITY
 * NOR ITS EMPLOYEES BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, 
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY 
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT 
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE 
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * ====================================================================
 *
 */
/*
 * continuous.c - Simple pocketsphinx command-line application to test
 *                both continuous listening/silence filtering from microphone
 *                and continuous file transcription.
 */

/*
 * This is a simple example of pocketsphinx application that uses continuous listening
 * with silence filtering to automatically segment a continuous stream of audio input
 * into utterances that are then decoded.
 * 
 * Remarks:
 *   - Each utterance is ended when a silence segment of at least 1 sec is recognized.
 *   - Single-threaded implementation for portability.
 *   - Uses audio library; can be replaced with an equivalent custom library.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#if !defined(_WIN32_WCE)
#include <signal.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#endif
#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(GNUWINCE)
#include <time.h>
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#endif

#include <sphinxbase/err.h>
#include <sphinxbase/ad.h>

#include "pocketsphinx.h"

static const arg_t cont_args_def[] = {
    POCKETSPHINX_OPTIONS,
    /* Argument file. */
    {"-argfile",
     ARG_STRING,
     NULL,
     "Argument file giving extra arguments."},
    {"-adcdev",
     ARG_STRING,
     NULL,
     "Name of audio device to use for input."},
    {"-infile",
     ARG_STRING,
     NULL,
     "Audio file to transcribe."},
    {"-time",
     ARG_BOOLEAN,
     "no",
     "Print word times in file transcription."},
    CMDLN_EMPTY_OPTION
};

static ps_decoder_t *ps;
static cmd_ln_t *config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
                                     "-hmm", "/home/bsnayak/Trainguard_MT2/pocketsphinx/model9/hmm/trainguard/",
                                     "-jsgf",  "/home/bsnayak/Trainguard_MT2/pocketsphinx/model9/lm2/trainguardmt_adv_2.jsgf",
                                     "-dict",  "/home/bsnayak/Trainguard_MT2/pocketsphinx/model9/dict/trainguard.dic",
                                     NULL);




static FILE *rawfd;

static void
print_word_times(int32 start)
{
    ps_seg_t *iter = ps_seg_iter(ps, NULL);
    while (iter != NULL) {
        int32 sf, ef, pprob;
        float conf;

        ps_seg_frames(iter, &sf, &ef);
        pprob = ps_seg_prob(iter, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        conf = logmath_exp(ps_get_logmath(ps), pprob);
        printf("%s %f %f %f\n", ps_seg_word(iter), (sf + start) / 100.0,
               (ef + start) / 100.0, conf);
        iter = ps_seg_next(iter);
    }
}

/*
 * Continuous recognition from a file
 */
static void
recognize_from_file()
{

    int16 adbuf[4096];

    const char *hyp;
    const char *uttid;

    int32 k;
    uint8 cur_vad_state, vad_state;

    char waveheader[44];
    if ((rawfd = fopen(cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-infile"), "rb")) == NULL) {
        E_FATAL_SYSTEM("Failed to open file '%s' for reading",
                       cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-infile"));
    }

    //skip wav header
    fread(waveheader, 1, 44, rawfd);
    cur_vad_state = 0;
    ps_start_utt(ps, NULL);
    while ((k = fread(adbuf, sizeof(int16), 4096, rawfd)) > 0) {
        ps_process_raw(ps, adbuf, k, FALSE, FALSE);
        vad_state = ps_get_vad_state(ps);
        if (cur_vad_state && !vad_state) {
            //speech->silence transition,
            //time to end utterance and start new one
            ps_end_utt(ps);
            hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL, &uttid);
            printf("%s: %s\n", uttid, hyp);
            fflush(stdout);
            ps_start_utt(ps, NULL);
        }
        cur_vad_state = vad_state;
    }
    ps_end_utt(ps);
    hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL, &uttid);
    printf("%s: %s\n", uttid, hyp);
    fflush(stdout);

    fclose(rawfd);
}

/* Sleep for specified msec */
static void
sleep_msec(int32 ms)
{
#if (defined(WIN32) && !defined(GNUWINCE)) || defined(_WIN32_WCE)
    Sleep(ms);
#else
    /* ------------------- Unix ------------------ */
    struct timeval tmo;

    tmo.tv_sec = 0;
    tmo.tv_usec = ms * 1000;

    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tmo);
#endif
}

/*
 * Main utterance processing loop:
 *     for (;;) {
 *     start utterance and wait for speech to process
 *     decoding till end-of-utterance silence will be detected
 *     print utterance result;
 *     }
 */
static void
recognize_from_microphone()
{
    ad_rec_t *ad;
    int16 adbuf[4096];
    uint8 cur_vad_state, vad_state;
    int32 k;
    char const *hyp;
    char const *uttid;

    if ((ad = ad_open_dev(cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-adcdev"),
                          (int) cmd_ln_float32_r(config,
                                                 "-samprate"))) == NULL)
        E_FATAL("Failed to open audio device\n");
    if (ad_start_rec(ad) < 0)
        E_FATAL("Failed to start recording\n");

    if (ps_start_utt(ps, NULL) < 0)
        E_FATAL("Failed to start utterance\n");
    cur_vad_state = 0;
    /* Indicate listening for next utterance */
    printf("READY....\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);
    for (;;) {
        if ((k = ad_read(ad, adbuf, 4096)) < 0)
            E_FATAL("Failed to read audio\n");
        sleep_msec(100);
        ps_process_raw(ps, adbuf, k, FALSE, FALSE);
        vad_state = ps_get_vad_state(ps);
        if (vad_state && !cur_vad_state) {
            //silence -> speech transition,
            // let user know that he is heard
            printf("Listening...\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        if (!vad_state && cur_vad_state) {
            //speech -> silence transition, 
            //time to start new utterance
            ps_end_utt(ps);
            hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL, &uttid);
            printf("%s: %s\n", uttid, hyp);
            fflush(stdout);
            //Exit if the first word spoken was GOODBYE
            if (hyp && (strcmp(hyp, "good bye") == 0))
                break;
            if (ps_start_utt(ps, NULL) < 0)
                E_FATAL("Failed to start utterance\n");
            /* Indicate listening for next utterance */
            printf("READY....\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            fflush(stderr);
        }
        cur_vad_state = vad_state;
    }
    ad_close(ad);
}

static jmp_buf jbuf;
static void
sighandler(int signo)
{
    longjmp(jbuf, 1);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char const *cfg;
/*
    config = cmd_ln_parse_r(NULL, cont_args_def, argc, argv, TRUE);

    ///* Handle argument file as -argfile. */
  /*  if (config && (cfg = cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-argfile")) != NULL) {
        config = cmd_ln_parse_file_r(config, cont_args_def, cfg, FALSE);
    }
    if (config == NULL)
        return 1;

    ps_default_search_args(config);
    ps = ps_init(config);
    if (ps == NULL)
        return 1;
*/


if (config == NULL)
return 1;
ps = ps_init(config);
if (ps == NULL)
return 1;

    E_INFO("%s COMPILED ON: %s, AT: %s\n\n", argv[0], __DATE__, __TIME__);

    if (cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-infile") != NULL) {
        recognize_from_file();
    }
    else {

        /* Make sure we exit cleanly (needed for profiling among other things) */
        /* Signals seem to be broken in arm-wince-pe. */
#if !defined(GNUWINCE) && !defined(_WIN32_WCE) && !defined(__SYMBIAN32__)
        signal(SIGINT, &sighandler);
#endif

        if (setjmp(jbuf) == 0) {
            recognize_from_microphone();
        }
    }

    ps_free(ps);
    return 0;
}

/** Silvio Moioli: Windows CE/Mobile entry point added. */
#if defined(_WIN32_WCE)
#pragma comment(linker,"/entry:mainWCRTStartup")
#include <windows.h>

//Windows Mobile has the Unicode main only
int
wmain(int32 argc, wchar_t * wargv[])
{
    char **argv;
    size_t wlen;
    size_t len;
    int i;

    argv = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        wlen = lstrlenW(wargv[i]);
        len = wcstombs(NULL, wargv[i], wlen);
        argv[i] = malloc(len + 1);
        wcstombs(argv[i], wargv[i], wlen);
    }

    //assuming ASCII parameters
    return main(argc, argv);
}
#endif
```

What do I have to do, to make it work with commands? To be recognized more efficiently even if there is a little mispronunciation or difference in accent.

Answer (score 2):

This is for those people who might also be having same problem, and the reason I'm answering my own question is that there is very little talk about the pocketsphinx speech recognition library and so is very hard to learn or work with because there is little of a community active. The official site doesn't provide an easy to understand guide, I found the official documentation more research bounded than a guide for a developer who just wants to build his/her application against the pocketsphinx library.

so if you have came across the line of successfully recognizing speech using the default language model and dictionary but you want efficiency and accuracy, then you have to create your own language model and dictionary or maybe you want to add some new accent to the default language model.

All you have to do is create a sample language corspus containing the words or sentences in a text file. Then create the language model (lm file) and dictionary (dic file) from it using the Sphinx lmtool .

The next thing is to instead of providing the defualt language model and dictionary during the compilation process, you should provide this new lm and dic files parameters.

And that is it, it will recognize the words very fast and with 100% accuracy. here is a link to the whole process: http://ghatage.com/tech/2012/12/13/Make-Pocketsphinx-recognize-new-words/

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of Crossposting (or to avoid it?) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10384/speech-processing-on-the-raspberry-pi/18222#18222 covers some essentials

Here it is for posterity.

I went with pocketsphinx_continuous and a [$4 sound card](http://www.amazon.co.uk/External-Sound-Adapter-Desktop-Notebook/dp/B000BUDHNQ).

To manage the fact that it needs to stop listening when using speech synth I used amixer to handle to input volume to the mic (this was recommended best practice by CMU as stop-starting engine will result in poorer recognition)

```
echo "SETTING MIC IN TO 15 (94%)" >> ./audio.log
amixer -c 1 set Mic 15 unmute 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

With a matching command to  mute the listening when the speech synth plays

```
FILE: mute.sh
#!/bin/sh

sleep $1;
amixer -c 1 set Mic 0 unmute >/dev/null 2>&1 ; 
echo  "** MIC OFF **" >> /home/pi/PIXIE/audio.log
```

To calculate the right times to mute for I just run soxi via lua and then set the unmute.sh (opposite of the mute.sh) to run "x" seconds from the startup.  There are no doubt lots of ways to handle this. I am happy with the results of this method.

LUA SNIPPET:

```
-- Begin parallel timing  
-- MUTE UNTIL THE SOUNDCARD FREES UP 
-- "filename" is a fully qualified path to a wav file 
-- outputted by voice synth in previous operation

-- GET THE LENGTH
local sample_length = io.popen('soxi -D '..filename);
local total_length  = sample_length:read("*a"); 
clean_length = string.gsub(total_length, "\n", "") +1;  
sample_length:close();

-- EXAMPLE LOGGING OUTPUT...
--os.execute( 'echo LENGTH WAS "'.. clean_length .. '" Seconds  >> ./audio.log');   



-- we are about to play something... 
-- MUTE, then schedule UNMUTE.sh in x seconds, then play synth output
-- (have unrolled mute.sh here for clarity)

os.execute( 'amixer -c 1 set Mic '..mic_level..' unmute 2>&1 >/dev/null ');
os.execute( 'echo "** MIC OFF **"  >> ./audio.log ');

-- EXAMPLE LOGGING OUTPUT...    
-- os.execute( 'echo PLAYING: "'.. filename..'" circa ' .. clean_length .. ' Seconds  >> ./audio.log ');

os.execute( './unmute.sh "'.. clean_length ..'" &');


-- THEN PLAY THE THING WHILE THE OTHER PROCESS IS SLEEPING  

os.execute( './sounds-uncached.sh '..filename..' 21000')
```

To actually grab the voice on the pi I use:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -bestpath 0 -adcdev plughw:1  -samprate 20000  \
-nfft 512 -ds2 -topn2 -maxwpf 5 -kdtreefn 3000 -kdmaxdepth 7 -kdmaxbbi 15 \
-pl_window 10 -lm ./LANGUAGE/0892-min.lm -dict ./LANGUAGE/0892-min.dic 2>&1 \
| tee -i 2>/dev/null >( sed -u -n -e 's/^.\{9\}: //p' ) \
>( sed -u -n -e 's/^READY//p' \
-e 's/^Listening//p' -e 's/^FATAL_ERROR: \"continuous\.c\"\, //p') \
> /dev/null
```

Again, there are other ways, but I like my output this way.

For the synth I used Cepstrals fledgling pi solution, but it's not available online you have to contact them directly to arrange to buy it and it is around $30 to buy. The results are acceptable however the speech does create some nasty clicks and pops, the company have replied saying they no longer have a RaspPi and are unwilling to improve the product. YMMV

The voice recognition sits at around 12% CPU when "idle", and spikes briefly when doing a chunk of recognition.

The voice creation spikes at about 50-80% when rendering.

The play / sox weighs in pretty heavily but I do apply real-time effects to the rendered voices as I play them ;)

The pi is heavily stripped down using every guide I could find to stop un-required services and runs in complete CLI mode. 800mhz over-clocked (smallest).

scaling_governor set to: performance

When fully running: it runs at about 50ºC in direct sunlight and 38ºC in the shade. I have heat sinks fitted.

Last point: I actually run all this gear out to "internet driven" AI as a nice extra.

The pi handles all this seamlessly, And playing out any networked audio in real-time, And fully looped audio to any other Unix box. etc.

to handle the large speech CPU overhead burden I have implemented an md5sum based caching system so the same utterences are not rendered twice. (about 1000 files @ 220 mb total covers 70% of the utterences I generally get back from the AI) this really helps bring the total CPU load down overall.

In précis this is all totally doable. however the voice recognition will only be as good as the quality of your mics, your language model, how specifically close your subjects voices are to the original intended audience (I use a en_US model on en_UK children, not perfect) and other minutia of detail that with effort you can whittle down to a decent result.

And for the record, I already did all this once before on a kindle (and that worked too with cmu sphinx and flite). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Scratte understood, enacted